# Raw SQL in ruby/rails scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to understand the difference between following two versions of rails scope. I believe their functionality is same. However I do observe a lot of difference in the generated SQL when using both of them.

**Version 1 (RAW SQL)**

```
scope :ignore_unavailable, lambda { 
  where(["Item.id not in (select id from Cars where Cars.status = 'NA'"])
}
```

**Version 2**

```
scope :ignore_unavailable, lambda { 
ids = Cars.select("id").where("status = 'NA'");
idsStr = ''
idsarr = ids.collect{|car| car.id}.flatten
where(["Item.id not in (" + idsarr.join(",") + ")"])
}
```

It seems to me that version 2 is generating more optimized queries than version 1, but I do not understand why is that.
Can anyone explain what could be happening here ?

Comment: Why do you think it's more optimized? if anything you've turned one db query into 2

Comment: why are you mixing item and car id? is there a relationship between them?

Comment: This is just one of the many scopes that are being used. I really do not have any clue as of now that why when I use V2 performance is really good where using V1 I can see a lot of extra SQL being generated and hence performance dip as well.

Comment: Add an example of what queries each version generates. They should be in the logs. Plus, even the second version contains excessive amount of SQL. More than it should.

Comment: I have updated this to a more relevant question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692461/writing-not-in-sql-query-using-arel