# Writing "not in" sql query using AREL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have a scope defined as follows:

```
scope :ignore_unavailable, lambda { 
  where([ "Item.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Cars WHERE Cars.status = 'NA'" ])
}
```

Currently its using hardcoded tables names. How can I improve it using frameworks like Arel ?
Will appreciate any help here.

I am on Rails 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using rails 4, one way would be

```
scope :ignore_unavailable, lambda {
  where.not(id: Car.where(:status => "NA").pluck(:id))
}
```

For rails 3

```
scope :ignore_unavailable, lambda {
  where("id not in (?)", Car.where(:status => "NA").pluck(:id))
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I am on rails 3.2

Comment: Updated my answer for rails 3

Comment: Thanks. This is great! One question though, Wont we be executing two SQL queries here instead of one like in original case ?

Comment: subqueries are actually bad. Performance wise having two queries might be better than having the subquery in your case. Read this blog, http://www.percona.com/blog/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/

Comment: @usha Subqueries are not “bad”. Loading an array of potentially millions of items out of laziness is “bad”.

Answer (score 13):

Since the task description asks for an answer using AREL, I present following:

```
class Car
  scope :available, -> { where(arel_table[:status].not_in(['NA'])) }
end

class Item
  scope :available, -> { where(:id => Car.available) }
end
```

The sql should be something like the following:

```sql
SELECT [items].*
FROM [items]
WHERE [item].[id] IN (
    SELECT [cars].[id]
    FROM [cars]
    WHERE [car].[status] NOT IN ('NA')
  )
```

Obviously, rails 4 has the `not` scope, so this is a solution for rails 3.

The above code has two benefits:

- It performs a single query
- The table columns are correctly namespaced (unlike when using raw sql)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had problems with namespaces in a complex query, only Arel could help me here. :)